# Nodejs req.params is []

Tags: node.js

In my Nodejs app,I send a request,but the `req.params` return `[]`

```
res.send(req.params);
```

But I get the `Form Data` from the chrome:

```
title:Hello world!
site:http://www.baidu.com
begdt:2013-12-31 02:25
enddt:2014-01-01 10:00
category:lottery
cover:face111.jpg
editorValue:<p>hello world hehe!</p>
```

Where the error is?

Comment: Can you confirm you're using express ? What version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params).
`req.params` contains matched route parameters only.

POST data is sent in `req.body`.

Comment: Thanks,I am a beginner of Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Are you using express and is your form submitted in POST ? If so use

```
req.param('title')
```

This has the advantage of also working if the query is submitted in GET (for example if you use `all`).